# dtype: float64 0.0 Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am still quite new to Pandas.  So I hope you don’t hold against me.  But I a few interesting questions I want to test.

So I notice

`dfzaga = df1["GA3334"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)` create nice numbers

```
Nice numbers
38    77.0
39     NaN
```

So why?

```
dfz = df1["GA3334"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float) -df1["GA333"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)      

##
dfz = df1["GA3334"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float) + df1["GA333"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Produce

```
dtype: float64
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
```

Should not Ga333 = 2 and ga3334 = 77

```
ga3334 – ga333 = 75
not 0.0
```

Comment: I think typo, you subtract same column `GA333 - GA333`

Comment: Still problem? Or `GA333` to `GA334` solve it?

Comment: @jezrael Ha ye I must autocorrect in brain =]

Comment: Its happen ;) No problem... Nice weekend ;)

Comment: @jezrael I mean I correct table above. The problem still appear

Comment: It should working... Are data confidental?

Comment: @jezrael No data not confidential.

Comment: Hmmm, is posible share it? gdocs, dropbox, wetransfer.. or send me file to my email in my profile? Because it seems some data dependent problem...

Comment: @jezrae I see no host file so I host public: https://ufile.io/vxoxs . I try new csv too

Comment: I am a bit confused, there are no float numeric saved as strings nor columns `GA333, GA334`... Do you upload correct file?

Comment: @jezrael wrong file :) same issue.  Try minus columns K&G. dfz = df1["K"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float) - df1["G"].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)

Comment: This is weird file, I cannot read it in pandas :(